# Next 13 (experimental app folder) problem generating dynamic routes with queries

Tags: next.js, graphql, jsx, apollo-client, dynamic-routing

I'm making a Dog's shelter web (non profit) and I'm trying to generate dynamic routes for a list of dogs.
I'm using Next.js 13 with experimental app folder, also using @apollo/client and graphql.
This is a summary of how the files and codes look like:

./libs/client.js

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

./graphql/dogs.js

```
const { gql } = require("@apollo/client");

export const GET_DOGGIES = gql`
  query GetDoggies {
    dogs(pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 30 }) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const GET_DOG = gql`
  query GetDog($slug: String!) {
    dog(slug: $slug) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          name
          desc
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The dog's list page looks something like this (I only left the necessary):
./app/dogs/page.jsx

```
"use client";

// REACT/NEXT
import Link from "next/link";

// GRAPHQL
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "@/libs/client";
import { GET_DOGGIES } from "@/graphql/dogs";
/* */

export default function Dogs() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DOGGIES, { client });

  if (loading) return <p>LOADING</p>;
  if (error) return <p>ERROR</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Doggies</h1>
      {data.dogs.data.map((d) => (
        <Link key={d.id} href={`/dogs/${d.attributes.slug}`}>
          <h1>{d.attributes.name}</h1>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And finally the dynamic route file looks like this:
./app/dogs/[slug]/page.jsx

```
"use client"

import { client } from "@/libs/graphql";
import { GET_DOGGIES } from "@/graphql/perritos";
import { GET_DOG } from "@/graphql/perritos";
/* */

export default function Doggie({ dog }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{dog.attributes.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_DOGGIES,
  });

  const paths = data.dogs.data.map((d) => ({
    params: { slug: d.attributes.slug },
  }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: GET_DOG,
    variables: { slug: params.slug },
  });

  return {
    props: { dog: data.dog.data },
  };
}
```

The error comes up when trying to go to a single dog Link, I'm gettig dog: undefined when console.log'ing.
The rest of the pages work fine. The only error is with the dynamic routes.
I've done this before but it's not working with this version of Nextjs. And I've already done a lot with the website to change everything to earlier versions.
So please help.

Comment: getStaticPaths and getStaticProps are not supported by NEXTJS 13

Comment: Refer to https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/generate-static-params to make it work with NEXTJS 13

Comment: @Singh `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` ARE supported on Next.js 13, just not on `app` directory. It's important to make the distinction.

Comment: @ivanatias My bad, didn't specified the APP folder.